# Difference between node and site

Tags: tangle, iota-network

In the whitepaper is written:

> A quick note on terminology: sites are transactions represented on the tangle
>   graph. The network is composed of nodes; that is, nodes are entities that issue and validate transactions

I am not able to understand the difference between this two terms because they are the same for me.

How are the nodes represented in the tange? Because for me, each node is a transaction represented in the DAG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we talk about nodes in IOTA we generally don't mean **sites inside of the directed acyclic graph**, the tangle, like transactions but **nodes inside of the network graph**. A node is basically just a device that sends transactions (sites) to its neighbours. The neighbours are devices as well and they are connected with each other through bluetooth, a network, the internet, ...

There are [different kinds of nodes](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/1175/10). A full node for example stores the tangle. So the tangle is a graph inside of (almost) every node of the "bigger network graph".